# BOOT0 vs BOOT1 circuit design in STM32f103 (ST-LINK)

Tags: jtag, programmer, swd, st-link, stm32f1

I have a question about designing st-link v2. According to the schematics provided by **st.com** Please help me in analyzing this schematic. Why **boot0** was **pulldown** with a 100k resistor but connected boot1 without **GND** resistor.

According to the **AN2586**, the pin boot0 and boot1 must be connected to a **VCC** or **GND** 10k resistor.
But this point is not met

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Right below Figure 10 of [AN2586](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/6c/a3/24/49/a5/d4/4a/db/CD00164185.pdf/files/CD00164185.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00164185.pdf) it mentions:

> Resistor values are given only as a typical example.

These pins can be tied directly to VDD or GND, but it is common practice to use resistors for a few reasons.

1. Series resistors can provide some current-limiting protection to the microcontroller pins.
2. Putting at least one resistor between the pin and VDD/GND allows for easier rework if the initial design assumptions/requirements change (e.g. oh no, we want to boot from system memory now instead of main FLASH memeory!).
3. Adding resistors to both VDD and GND -- and not populating one of them -- allows for switching between boot configurations with only a bill of materials (BOM) change instead of rerouting a PCB in order to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.